# Adding a new column with buttons in gridview and binding data to it

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have added a button for Print in my gridview table as follows

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="522px">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Story_number" HeaderText="Story_number" 
                            SortExpression="Story_number" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Memory_card" HeaderText="Memory_card" 
                            SortExpression="Memory_card" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Story_Name" HeaderText="Story_Name" 
                            SortExpression="Story_Name" />
                        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="print" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Please help me with the c# code for this button. When the button is pressed I need it to redirect to a page (print.aspx). I have been trying the following code but it does not work .Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Session["id"] = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
Response.Redirect("Print.aspx");
```

Comment: Question title and body is completely different - title says adding column, body says how to get 1st cell text?

Comment: also where are you trying the last two lines of your code?
And what happens when you click the print button, does it refresh the page or something else ...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I want is to add a print button to Gridview that when clicked creates a session Variable of the ID of the selected row and redirects to a new web page

Comment: I am not sure were to use it as I usually use On SelectedIndexChanged when I use the built in Select button. I would like your help as I am new to this

Comment: You can have select index change event for gridview, then set the value of selected row to session and on button click just redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of buttonField, use template field

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ButtonPrint" runat="server" CssClass="yourCssClassIsNeedIt" OnClick="printRegFunction"
            CommandArgument='<%# Bind("id") %>' ImageUrl="images/button.png"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

your server code or behind code here:

```
protected void printRegFunction(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Session["id"] = ((ImageButton)sender).CommandArgument;
        Response.Redirect("Print.aspx");

    }
```

Comment: Thank You Exactly what I wanted.